# How to package BlackBerry 6 application using Ripple emulator?

Tags: blackberry, package, blackberry-webworks, ripple, blackberry-os6

As per the link  [Packaging BlackBerry 6 Application](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/hello-world/previewing-application-blackberry-6-7/) 
I have set up all the environment for packaging BlackBerry 6 project.
 Followed the steps and when clicked on **package** option in **ripple emulator**, packaging is not done.

Steps followed:

2. **Installed WebWorks SDK** at path - C:\BBApp\webworksSDK
3. **Installed Java SDK 1.7 ; 32 Bit** at path - C:\BBApp\installations\java32
4. Installed BlackBerry Java Plug-in 2.0.0, BB Java SDK 6.0.0 through install new software Update Site - ://www.blackberry.com/developers/jar/win/java
5. Added Ripple emulator(BETA) extension to chrome through chrome web store.
6. Previewed the application in the console Enabled Ripple by
   clicking **Enable** from the extension’s menu in Chrome.
7. Chosen **WebWorks (2.0.0)** to proceed with previewing the application.
8. In Ripple, on the right menu, clicked **Build**, and then clicked **Settings**… at the bottom.
9. **SDK Path**: Path given where BlackBerry WebWorks SDK is
   installed - C:\BBApp\webworksSDK
10. **Project root:** The root folder of your project.
     C:\Users\NARESH\workspace2\BB6\apps\BB6APP\blackberry\native
11. **Archive Name**: BB6
12. **Output Folder:** specified to path - C:\BBoutput

    **Password:**  Signing is NOT required to run the application in the BlackBerry
    Simulator. left this field blank

    **Simulator:** Optional- left blank

When clicked on **PACKAGE** no packaging is done, have i missed anything? please suggest, attached the screen shots of the process.

Please find the [Picture Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrJSs.png)

Comment: Or is there any other way to package the application other than Ripple Emulator?

Comment: It would be helpful if some one could answer this question

Comment: There are times when packaging from Ripple would not work, command line might be another alternative. Hope this helps. https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v1_0/compiling_packaging_your_ww_app_1866977_11.html